# Error deploying a meteor app

Tags: deployment, meteor

When deploying a meteor app, I run into this error:

```
Errors prevented deploying:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/andyjiang/Developer/hackathon/meteor/instachat/.meteor/local/build_tar/bundle/app/instachat.js'
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:582:18)
    at Object._.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:280:10)
    at _.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:276:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object._.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:274:9)
    at _.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:276:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object._.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:274:9)
    at _.extend.write_to_directory (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/bundler.js:808:11)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/bundler.js:887:12)
    at deployToServer (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/deploy.js:95:24)
    at deployCmd (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/deploy.js:78:7)
    at exports.inFiber (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12)

/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/fiber-helpers.js:25
    }).run();
       ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/andyjiang/Developer/hackathon/meteor/instachat/.meteor/local/build_tar/bundle/app/instachat.js'
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:582:18)
    at Object._.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:280:10)
    at _.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:276:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object._.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:274:9)
    at _.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:276:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object._.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:274:9)
    at _.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:276:15)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object._.extend.rm_recursive (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/files.js:274:9)
    at deployToServer (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/deploy.js:101:11)
    at deployCmd (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/deploy.js:78:7)
    at exports.inFiber (/Users/andyjiang/.meteor/tools/11f45b3996/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12)
```

The app runs fine locally. I've deployed other Meteor apps without any issues, as well. Any idea what the error could be?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Looks like you don't have permission to execute meteor deploy from that directory. Have you tried `sudo` ?